# Run react native when application is closed

Tags: react-native, background-process, react-native-ios

Hello guys i know that there are few other questions that maybe cover this, but none of them answered my problem.

I want to run some actions even if my application is in the background or closed, or to trigger specific actions with api call from server. I need to use it for push notifications and for other actions as well and i need this for iOS and for Android. 
Is there any library out there or some feature that i can use ?

Comment: check headless js section of react native